# What does 'typename Enable = void' mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I found `typename Enable = void` is defined in the [ProtoBuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/reflection.h#L47),

```
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct RefTypeTraits;
```

However, I cannot find the `Enable` is used in this [header file](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/reflection.h), which confuse me. What does `typename Enable = void` mean in template?

Answer (score 12):

It is to allow [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) with template specialization, as something like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct RefTypeTraits<T, std::enable_if_t<some_condition<T>::value>>
{
    // ... specialization for T which respects condition
};
```

Since C++20, we can specialize with [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) to avoid this needed extra template parameter.

Comment: How does it allow SFINAE? As in your example, the second template parameter `typename Enabled = void` is not defined.

Comment: @Thomson: `std::enable_if_t<condition_v<T>>` translates to `void` on success, but on failure, instead of error, that specialization is just discarded.

Answer (score 8):

Your template just has two template parameters.  The second one is called "Enabled" and it has the default type of "void".  This is a trick to allow [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) later on.

Comment: [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)