# c++ template argument declaration

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I am reading reference about [enable_if on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). In the example section. I have a question about the template declaration in the code:

```
// #4, enabled via a template parameter
template<class T,
         typename std::enable_if<
             !std::is_trivially_destructible<T>{} &&
             (std::is_class<T>{} || std::is_union<T>{}),
            int>::type = 0>
void destroy(T* t)
{
    std::cout << "destroying non-trivially destructible T\n";
    t->~T();
}
```

If the condition of the std::enable_if() is satisfied. The declaration can be rewrote as:

```
 template<class T, typename std::enable_if_t<true,int> = 0> // #1
```

Since the possible implementation of enable_if is:

```
template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

The #1 is equivalent to the following statement:

```
template<typename T, typename int = 0>
```

which is an ill-formed statement. The compiler spits an error message:

```
error: two or more data types in declaration of 'parameter'
 template<typename T, typename int = 0>
```

My question is: What is the correctly way to understand the `typename std::enable_if_t<true,int> = 0` in the template declaration.

---

And a similar question I have is the example followed by #4
The #5 :

```
// #5, enabled via a template parameter
template<class T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value> >
void destroy(T* t) // note, function signature is unmodified
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < std::extent<T>::value; ++i) {
        destroy((*t)[i]);
    }
}
```

When the condition of the enable_if() is satisfied, the declaration should be something like：

```
template<class T, typename = X > // X is a type name
```

How comes the `typename=X` can be compiled.

Thanks,

Rong

Comment: You are slightly mistaken. `template<class T, typename std::enable_if<true,int>::type = 0>` is equivalent to `template<class T, int = 0>`.  You don't need to `typename` to resolve the dependent type when you use `std::enable_of_t`,

Comment: Or you can use `typename` with a variadic version: `typename std::enable_if<condition, T>::type ...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459640/what-does-typename-enable-void-mean